# Command binding in external itemtemplate of xamarin.forms listview?

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Im using mvvm and viewmodel locator.Im using button commands or listview itemtap behaviors with no problem.But in one of my page I need to use  external itemtemplate (resources).In this template i can bind labels with no problem.But I cant Bind command of button,I get this error "Can't resolve name on Element" .

```
here is the external custom cell


<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:core="clr-namespace:paux;assembly=paux"
              xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:paux.Controls;assembly=paux"
               xmlns:xlabs="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
              xmlns:base="clr-namespace:paux.Base;assembly=paux"   
              x:Class="paux.Controls.Cells.CustomDonemCell">   <ViewCell.View>
          <Grid  
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
          <Grid  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid    Grid.Row="0">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <StackLayout
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="0,16,0,0"
                  Orientation="Vertical"
                  Spacing="0"
                  VerticalOptions="Start">    -           
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.mybuttonClicked, Source={x:Reference Name=mylistView}}"   CommandParameter="{Binding id}"    Text="My Button"/>
                <controls:MultiLineLabel Text="{Binding BolumAdi}"    Lines="2"             VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"             LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                 Margin="0,0,0,3"/>        
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>   </ViewCell.View> </ViewCell>
```

This is the Page ,with templateselector (its working fine)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:paux.Behavior;assembly=paux"
                  xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:paux.Animations;assembly=paux"
                  xmlns:triggers="clr-namespace:paux.Triggers;assembly=paux"
                 xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:paux.Effects;assembly=paux"
                 xmlns:templateSelectors="clr-namespace:paux.TemplateSelectors;assembly=paux"    
                 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:paux.Converters;assembly=paux"
                 x:Class="paux.Pages.PageOgrenciDonem" >
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <templateSelectors:DataTemplateSelector x:Key="ogrenciDonemTemplate" />  
    </ResourceDictionary>  
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListView
        x:Name="mylistView"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        ItemsSource="{Binding OgrencilikList, Mode=OneWay}"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        SeparatorVisibility="None"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ogrenciDonemTemplate}" >
      <ListView.Margin>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    Android="8"
                    WinPhone="8"/>
      </ListView.Margin>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and in the viewmodel

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty TestCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("TestCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomDonemCell), null);
    public ICommand TestCommand => new Command<detay>(testclickevent);
    private async void testclickevent(detay item)
    {  await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<detayviewmodel(item.id.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: if you provide sample project it will be easier to quickly reproduce and try to fix

Comment: sorry for late response ,I reproduce this with clean simple project, you can quickly look from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yssmmncbppwd3d/testapp.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is where to define your handler. You defined it in the PageTestViewModel but in xaml this command is not defined for the list or page model. It is defined for the ITEM. So, you have 3 options. You don't have to define both OnButtonClicked and TestCommand, I just show it as an option. If you define both you will get called in 2 places (see below)

```
<Button Clicked="OnButtonClicked" Command="{Binding  TestCommand}"   CommandParameter="{Binding id}"    Text="My Button"/>
```

1. To be called via OnButtonClicked

   ```
   public partial class CustomCell : ViewCell
   {
       public CustomCell()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {

       }

   }
   ```
2. To be called in item

   ```
   public class testdata
       {
           public string id { get; set; }

           public Command TestCommand
           {
               get
               {

                   return new Command((o) =>
                   {
                       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item " + o.ToString());
                   });
               }
           }
       }
   ```
3. To be called in PageTestViewModel where you wanted to be called you need to specify path to your model. This is more complicated. Send me a message if previous 2 methods don't work for you. But this is going to be tricky as you have your ViewCell xaml in separate file, so you cannot access page name or list name. I am not sure if it is good design to specify handler in cell which leaves in the top-level model. You might want to use one of 2 handlers I suggested and subscribe for events which will be fired from those handlers up.

Comment: Thanks Yuri ,I wanted to call from viewmodel ,try to use path but cant succeed it.Because when I give path (Source={x:Reference Name=mylistView}) but it gives error because listview is in the page and viewcell is in the resource.Better I use second method you said.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you describe 3rd solution? I have same problem, I want to Bind Command to Button, which is on another file in Data Template for ListView and Command is defined in ViewModel.

Comment: @kaktusas2598 You have to use Binding Path